# What is this hardcoded GET request in one of my node_modules? Is it malicious code?

Tags: javascript, code-injection

While I was developing locally on my `localhost:8080` with my Vue.js app after a while I saw these two GET requests. I don't want to sound paranoid but I am curious why there are hardcoded URL calls in the `webpack-dev-server` dependency in `node_modules`. I just can't wrap my head around these. I am unsure if I saw that before or not. Was just curious and took a deeper look.

[image: ine]

```
socket(socketUrl, onSocketMessage);
/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(this, "?http://192.168.80.197:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node"))//# sourceURL=[module]
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9...
```

```
xetra11@pop-os:~$ whois 192.168.80.197

OrgName:        Internet Assigned Numbers Authority
OrgId:          IANA
Address:        12025 Waterfront Drive
Address:        Suite 300
City:           Los Angeles
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     90292
Country:        US
```

Definitely sure I am overreacting but still am just curious :)

Comment: You're asking if the local IP call is malicious? Perhaps it's related to socksjs and you might find some answers looking into that?

Comment: its the hmr socket (tip look at the url it clearly shows webpack-dev-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That IP address is in a [private network block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), which is why you see IANA as the owner. All `192.168.x.x` addresses are. (Also `10.x.x.x` and `172.16.0.0` through `172.31.255.255`.) These are addresses that aren't routed publicly. They're for private (local) networks.

I suspect that 192.168.80.197 is the local address of your workstation, assigned by your router, and that the address was baked into those scripts by your Webpack build. You can check that by doing `ip addr show` on a *nix box or `ipconfig` on a Windows box.

Alternatively, it's the local address of some project author who accidentally checked in scripts with their then-current local address baked into them. :-)